# Why driver memory is not in my Spark context configuration?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

When I run the following command:

```sh
spark-submit --name "My app" --master "local[*]" --py-files main.py --driver-memory 12g --executor-memory 12g
```

With the following code in my `main.py`:

```py
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
print(sc.getConf().getAll())
```

Driver memory and executor memory do not appear in the configuration. Even though I'm in local mode, I guess I should at least have the driver memory in the configuration.

Any ideas why it is not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your submit command is not correct. The confs should come before the `.py` file.  See [Launching Applications with spark-submit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit):

> ```
>  ./bin/spark-submit \
>   --class <main-class> \
>   --master <master-url> \
>   --deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
>   --conf <key>=<value> \
>   ... # other options
>   <application-jar> \
>   [application-arguments]
> ```
>
> [...] For Python applications, simply pass a  `.py` file in the place of `<application-jar>` instead of a JAR, and add Python `.zip`, `.egg` or `.py` files to the search path with `--py-files`.

This is said, your command shoud be like this:

```bash
spark-submit --name "My app" \
--master "local[*]" \
--driver-memory 12g \
--conf spark.executor.memory=12g \
/path_to/main.py
```